# Unable to fix CSSLint error "Expected RBRACE" on CSS grid rule

Tags: css, gruntjs, stylus, csslint

I'm using Stylus and Grunt with CSS Lint and am getting an error on this rule:

```
.example
  grid-template-columns repeat(auto-fill, minmax(50%, 1fr))
```

The error I get is:

```
>> ERROR: Expected RBRACE at line 9, col 147897. This rule looks for recoverable syntax errors. (errors) Browsers: All
```

Adding line exceptions as in the following (as described in [the docs](https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/Ignoring-parts-of-CSS-during-linting)) doesn't get rid of the error:

```
.example
  /* csslint ignore:start */
  grid-template-columns repeat(auto-fill, minmax(50%, 1fr))
  /* csslint ignore:end */
```

Not sure how to ignore the rule inline or in the `.csslintrc` file either since I can't determine what rule is being broken. Any ideas?

Comment: I ran into the same problem today. As far as I can tell from google, csslint just hasn't implemented support for grid.